How to close .mdf file after used by SqlConnection variable
I'm use SqlConnection variable conn to connect to database1.mdf file. Then I use OpenFileDialog and select file database1.mdf to open, but I get the message

This file is in use

from the OpenFileDialog. How do I close that file before reopening it?
This is my code for event Button1_Click. I have rewritten code for simpler. My original code had cn as a global variable so I can't use using keyword for this.
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\CSDL\\DB_Project\\DataBase\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True");

        cn.Open();
        cn.Close();
        
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }

And this is the message of opendialog when I try to open database1.mdf:
enter image description here
I tried using cn.Dispose(); but it didn't work. I have searched on the internet but there are no solutions for this problem.
I want to know how to close that .mdf file after using by SqlConnection variable. Thanks.

You don't "open and close" .mdf files - those are SQL Server files - and as the name already implies - it's a server product and you should let it handle all the file details itself and stay out of that. Just create your database in SQL Server, refer to it via its database name, and let the SQL Server engine handle all the details of file management ....

I found a way to solve my problem. It's my fault for not explaining clearly. I set openFileDialog1's property to false and changed things from my original intent. However the answer that "I don't open and close .mdf files" is not the answer I wanted for my original purpose. Once again I apologize for not explaining clearly. What I want to do in the //Do something part is execute the command: File.Copy("C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\CSDL\DB_Project\DataBase\Database1.mdf", "C: \\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Database1.mdf"); Although I have found a way to solve the problem, if anyone has a way for me to execute that command, please let me know. Thanks everyone.
